# "multiple Lua VMs detected" error with c module lua 5.3

Tags: c, lua

I have looked at every post pertaining the "multiple Lua VMs detected" error and none of their answers worked. I have done everything [the lua.org building](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingModules) guide says to compile it and it still shows the error. Using visual studio 2019 causes an unresolved external symbol error and using the GCC command without -llua also causes unresolved symbols. Any ideas. I am using version lua 5.3.2 from the binary compiled with the provided make file.

this is the code I am trying to use

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int test_function(lua_State* L)
{

    return 0;
}

static const luaL_Reg testlib[] = {
    {"test_function", test_function},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl luaopen_testlib(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L, testlib);

    return 1;
};
```

```
local lib, err = package.loadlib([[module.dll]], "luaopen_testlib")

if lib ~= nil then
    --multiple Lua VMs detected
    lib()
else
    print(err)
end
```

Comment: What program are you using to load the library you're building? Are you just `require()`ing it from the Lua standalone interpreter?

Comment: it is a cheat with an embedded interpreter. i am using package.loadlib

Comment: You have 2 Lua VMs: one in the `module.dll` and another in the host executable.  Such configuration is prohibited until Lua 5.4

Comment: how do i remove the instance in the module dll

Comment: Remove it by deleting `#include "lua.h"` :-)  But you would be unable to call `luaL_newlib`

Comment: that defeats the purpose of the module. I am trying to add a c function into the lua global namespace which requires newlib

Comment: You can store C function in the DLL, but you should invoke `newlib` from the host executable.

Comment: i dont have access the executable. i am trying to use this as a library

Comment: You should somehow get the address of function newlib used by the host executable and invoke it from your DLL.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - can you summarise how Lua54 solves this? I have tried it and it works. But I would like to know how/why. I have searched online for Lua 5.4 Multiple VMs etc.. but can't find any relevant info. Thanks.

Comment: @SimplSam - Unlike previous versions, Lua 5.4 VM does not have global state.  All the VM data is inside `lua_State` structure. It does not matter which code is accessing it.